# Air-flow dag example leveraging Kubernetes Operator to deploy a pod in Kubernetes Cluster using cluster api_key

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, minikube

I have followed the steps from [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/06/28/airflow-on-kubernetes-part-1-a-different-kind-of-operator/) and successfully launched Pods in Minikube.

Now I'm trying to launch Pods in Enterprise Kubernetes Cluster.

For that how to wrap `api_key` along with the KubernetesPodOperator arguments. 
I looked into the KubernetesPodOperator code and didn't find any arguments for `api_key`.

Could somebody help me out here with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `api_key` in a Kubernetes config file or the cluster context? You can specify a config file or cluster context.
The stuff in [the Airflow config](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L592) is mostly about the Kubernetes Executor and not the Operator.